# How to stop AWS Fargate container programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-fargate

Problem: We have a scheduled job (AWS Fargate + Lambda + DynamoDB) this will run every day. But due to some issue, if Container gets stuck, We need to stop the container and retrigger the same job again.

is there any way we can stop/timeout the AWS Fargate task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so on the console or via the AWS CLI. You'd probably want to use the [stop-task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/stop-task.html) API to do that. This requires you to grab the task ID first listing the tasks in your cluster and filter them based on what you need to filter (task definition I guess?).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to build additional logic. You can leverage built-in HEALTHCHECK feature.
You can read more info at [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) page

While creating your TASK definition, in the container section, you will see Advanced Container Configuration
There you can specify following attributes for HEALTHCHECK:

| Attribute | Description | Default Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Command | The healthcheck command, it can be one-liner command or a shell script call | None |
| Interval | The time period in seconds between each health check execution between 5 and 300 seconds. | 30 seconds |
| Timeout | The time period in seconds to wait for a health check to succeed before it is considered a failure between 2 and 60 seconds | 5 seconds |
| Start Period | waiting time to before doing health check(container booting time) . It can be 0-300seconds | Disabled |
| Retries | The number of times to retry a failed health check before the container is considered unhealthy between 1 and 10 retries | 3 retries |

So after specifying healthcheck one liner command or script with correct parameters,healthcheck will run continuously. Depending on the result of your HealthCheck command that you specified, you have 2 outcomes after each check execution

| Condition | HealthCheck Status |
| --- | --- |
| An exit code of 0 | Success |
| A non-zero exit code | Failure |

So after all consecutive checks if container fill all failure retries, then it will be determined as unhealthy,then it will be stopped and replaced automatically. You don't need extra controller,checker,tuner!
Just write a simple healthcheck which is really showing that your container is healthy.

The other side conditions are to take care;

- The task needs to be defined in a Service.
- Container health checks are supported for Fargate tasks if you are using platform version 1.1.0 or later.
- Container health checks are not supported for tasks that are part of a service that is configured to use a Classic Load Balancer.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the status of the tasks, stop and restart them with the ECS cli, and create a script for that.